# How to get the files inside a folder in Supporting Files in xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, filesystems, xcode4.2, nsbundle

I have done the following steps.
1. Created an xcode project and created a folder named "Images" inside Supporting Files.

1. Dragged and dropped 4 images into it. Tried to access those files using the following code

   ```
   NSString *pathString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Images" ofType:nil];
   NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathString error: nil];
   NSLog(@"the fileList is %d",[fileList count]);
   ```

The count is always 0. What should I do now? There are files inside it and I am able to use it in imageviews.

So what is the mistake that I am making?

Comment: anything, now i just want the count to be +1 minimum.

Comment: the app bundle doesn't make any folder/subfolders for your any resource in the xcode.

Comment: ok, that I know. But then how can I distinguish certain files in different folders. Is there no way?

Comment: though I have explained below in my answer yet you must refer this link :  http://mobiledevelopertips.com/xcode/xcode-folders-and-the-file-system-part-1.html

Answer (score 7):

The Xcode does not generate any folders in your app bundle that corresponds to groups. Any resources added are present in Copy Bundle Resources in your target's Build Phases. You then access your resource under [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] path.

But if you want to count files under any folder then while adding that folder you must check the option :

"Create folder references for any added folders."

This will create folders and sub-folders in the same hierarchy as you add them.Then you can easily count them in the same manner you are doing above...

Otherwise the app bundle has all of your resources at one place not in any folder as you say "Images".Use following code :

```
NSArray *fileList = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] error: nil];
NSLog(@"the fileList is %d",[fileList count]);
```

It will list all your resources.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSString *imagespath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:"yourimagename" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"images"];
```